# How to select all beginning character of the words if it was specific character?

Tags: php, regex, string

My real question is about Persian language *(right to left direction)*, But for simplification, I write is as English version in first:

I have this string:

```
$str = 'it is a test, also i like this word: "italic"';
```

Now I want to remove all `i` characters that are in the beginning of the word. some thing like this:

```
$newstr = 't s a test, also like this word: "italic"';
```

---

Also here is my **real version**:

```
$str = 'امروز هوا خوب است ولی دیروز خوب نبود و ویران کننده بود';
```

I want this: (I want to remove all `و` characters that are in the beginning of the word. It should be noted, as I said, Persian starts from the right)

```
$newstr = 'امروز هوا خوب است لی دیروز خوب نبود یران کننده بود';
```

---

Here is my try:

```
echo preg_replace('/و/u', '', $str);
//=> امرز ها خب است لی دیرز خب نبد یران کننده بد
```

as you see, I need to define just remove `و` characters if it was in the beginning of the word. How can I do that?

**Note:** `'/\bو/u'` does not work, because Persian starts from the right side.

Comment: Then, if it starts from the right side, try `'/ای\b/u'`.

Comment: @stribizhev actually I tested it already, I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: it works... http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/di6

Comment: I also think it works the way you wrote, but I guess you just want to also replace the optional whitespace after it: [`echo preg_replace('/\bو\s*/u', '', $str)`](https://ideone.com/l6jh2K).

Comment: @Salketer this is the output: `امروز هوا خوب است ولی دیروز خوب نبود و ویران کننده بود`. So it does not work.

Comment: @stribizhev Odd. It works in your fiddle, but does not work for me. anyway thanks :-)

Comment: Do you have your PHP files saved with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: @stribizhev I think so!

Comment: @stack the output string on the regex tester is exactly the string you are looking for according to your question...

Comment: @Salketer ok well, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using lookbehind like

```
/(?<=^|\s)i/
```

or

```
/(?<=^|\s)و/
```

to detect an `i`/`و` preceded by either `start of line` or a `space`. Or if the right to left makes it work the other way around (lookahead)

```
/i(?=$|\s)/
```

Regards.